# MongoDb how to cache MongoClient connection in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection, connection-pooling

I am using MongoClient in NodeJs to carry out Db operations, I am running into connection and db caching issues,
 where the application shows the db connections are getting disconnected while doing db operations
Following are the errors -

```
MongoError: MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db
    at MongoClient.db (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:313:11)
```

```
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:609:14)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1557:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}
```

```
Unable to connect with the mongoDb :  MongoError: Topology closed
    at NativeTopology.close (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:325:38)
    at /var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:267:21
    at maybePromise (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:719:3)
    at MongoClient.close (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:248:10)
```

**Following is my DB connection and closing code-**
I call the `client` method while going any db operation like findOne, insertOne, etc
 And `closeDBConnection` right before returning the API response.

```
import { MongoClient, Db } from "mongodb";

let cachedDb: Db = null;
let mongoClient: MongoClient = null;

export const client = async (): Promise<Db> => {
  if (cachedDb && await mongoClient.isConnected()) {
    console.info("cached db connection established");
    return cachedDb;
  }
  
  mongoClient = new MongoClient('db URL here', {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    connectTimeoutMS: 90000,
    poolSize: 10
  });
  try {
    await mongoClient.connect();

    if (await !mongoClient.isConnected()) {
      await mongoClient.connect(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Error : ", err);
          throw new Error(`Unable to connect MongoDb Client, Reason: ${err}`
          );
        }
      });
    }

    cachedDb = await mongoClient.db(await "DB name here");
    console.info("db connection established");
    return cachedDb;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in connecting to DB => ", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const closeDBConnection = async () => {
  try {
    if( mongoClient != null ){
      await mongoClient.close();
      mongoClient = null;
      cachedDb = null;

      console.log("db connection closed");
      return true;
    } 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in closeDBConnection => ", error);
    return false;
  } 
};
```

I've added `connectTimeoutMS: 90000,poolSize: 10` to increase the default settings of 30000 and 5 respectively.
 Will it resolve the above errors?
What is the ideal way to cache a db connection in NodeJS on AWS Lambda?

Ref -
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/MongoClient.html

Comment: Those errors look like it is not connecting in the first place, so the cache client is not connected.  Try validating the connection process without the caching wrappers.

Comment: @Joe I tried await `mongoClient.isConnected()`, what is the correct way?

Comment: The error `Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established` would seem to imply that the connection was never established.  Did the server log anything about the connection?

Comment: found the issue, it was due to connection drain, thanks Joe